# Merge two arrays with alternating values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I would like to merge 2 arrays with a different length:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = [1, 2];
```

The outcome I would expect is `["a", 1 ,"b", 2, "c", "d"]`

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "*what is the best way to do that*"? What is the expected result? "merging" is a rather broad concept.

Comment: Could you please write how should final result look like ?

Comment: by alternating values do you mean like 1 from array1 then one from array2 and so on?

Comment: You can simply use array1.concat(array2)

Comment: @pro what will be the complexity of concat()

Comment: So what did you try? Loop over shortest append the two, concat the remaining.... seems simple enough

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could iterate the min length of both array and build alternate elements and at the end push the rest.

```js
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    array2 = [1, 2],
    result = [],
    i, l = Math.min(array1.length, array2.length);
    
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    result.push(array1[i], array2[i]);
}
result.push(...array1.slice(l), ...array2.slice(l));

console.log(result);
```

Solution for an arbitrary count of arrays with a transposing algorithm and later flattening.

```js
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    array2 = [1, 2],
    result = [array1, array2]
        .reduce((r, a) => (a.forEach((a, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(a)), r), [])
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 21):

Here's another way you can do it using destructuring assignment -

```js
const interleave = ([ x, ...xs ], ys = []) =>
  x === undefined
    ? ys                             // base: no x
    : [ x, ...interleave (ys, xs) ]  // inductive: some x
        
console.log (interleave ([0, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5])) // [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]    
console.log (interleave ([0, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 7])) // [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 ]
console.log (interleave ([0, 2, 4], []))           // [ 0 2 4 ]
console.log (interleave ([], [1, 3, 5, 7]))        // [ 1 3 5 7 ]
console.log (interleave ([], []))                  // [ ]
```

And another variation that supports any number of input arrays -

```js
const interleave = ([ x, ...xs ], ...rest) =>
  x === undefined
    ? rest.length === 0
      ? []                               // base: no x, no rest
      : interleave (...rest)             // inductive: no x, some rest
    : [ x, ...interleave(...rest, xs) ]  // inductive: some x, some rest

console.log (interleave ([0, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5])) // [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]    
console.log (interleave ([0, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 7])) // [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 ]
console.log (interleave ([0, 2, 4], []))           // [ 0 2 4 ]
console.log (interleave ([], [1, 3, 5, 7]))        // [ 1 3 5 7 ]
console.log (interleave ([], []))                  // [ ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Create an array of tuples. Each tuple contains 1 element from each array, flatten by spreading the array of tuples, and adding the leftover items from the arrays:

```js
const a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const a2 = [1,2];
const l = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length);

const merged = [].concat(...Array.from({ length: l }, (_, i) => [a1[i], a2[i]]), a1.slice(l), a2.slice(l));
  
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Array.from()  with .filter() take 4.044921875ms and result.push() take 3.296630859375ms

Answer (score 6):

Here's a modern solution that takes any number of arrays:

```
const braidArrays = (...arrays) => {
  const braided = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(...arrays.map(a => a.length)); i++) {
    arrays.forEach((array) => {
      if (array[i] !== undefined) braided.push(array[i]);
    });
  }
  return braided;
};
```

Note that you could change `Math.max` to `Math.min` to only include up to the shortest array.

Here's a sample I/O:

```
braidArrays(['a','b','c','d'], [1,2,3], [99,98,97,96,95]);
// ['a', 1, 99, 'b', 2, 98, 'c', 3, 97, 'd', 96, 95]
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for a performance comparison i have done a file which compares some of the above functions.

The test was to merge two arrays with lengths 200 and 500. For each method the test was run 1000 times.

Here are the results ordered by the fastest (time):

1. [6.7ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061337)
2. [9.8ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516552)
3. [16.7ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061292)
4. [23.3ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748845)
5. [24.2ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55203901)
6. [151.7ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390875)
7. [297.8ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53518839)
8. [1.15s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061616)

Link to the [file](https://github.com/pkulcsarsz/js-method-comparison/blob/b34e504f92ccb49786a7387b49992d030a2cc0c9/alternateMerge.js)

Answer (score 1):

Another **ONELINER**:

```
const merge = (arr1, arr2) => ((arr1.length > arr2.length) ? arr1 : arr2).map((_,i)=>[arr1[i],arr2[i]]).flat().filter(Boolean);
```

explanation:

1. Take the longest array with the ternary conditional operator
2. Use map to create for each index a pair of elements from each array
3. Flatten the result
4. Remove the undefined

Answer (score 0):

**ONELINER**: I assume that `x=array1`, `y=array2`, x and y can be arbitrary arr

```
[...x,...y].reduce((l,c,i)=>(i<x.length&&l.push(x[i]),i<y.length&&l.push(y[i]),l),[])
```

working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/7m81gw2q/8/) (for 3 cases)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const array2 = [1, 2];
const mergeArrays = (a, b) => (a.length > b.length ? a : b)
  .reduce((acc, cur, i) => a[i] && b[i] ? [...acc, a[i], b[i]] : [...acc, cur], []);

console.log(mergeArrays(array1, array2)); // ["a",1 ,"b", 2, "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather simply using a splicing function within `reduce`:

```js
function splicer(array, element, index) {
    array.splice(index * 2, 0, element);
    return array;
}

function weave(array1, array2) {
    return array1.reduce(splicer, array2.slice());
}

let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = [1, 2];

let outcome = weave(array1, array2);

console.log(outcome);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit verbose solution that lets you choose which array goes first

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const b = [1, 4];
const combineAlternatingArrays = (a, b) => {
  let combined = [];
  const [shorter, larger] = [a, b].sort((a, b) => a.length -b.length);

  shorter.forEach((item, i) => {
    combined.push(larger[i], item);
  })
  combined.push(...larger.slice(shorter.length));

  return combined;
}
console.log(combineAlternatingArrays(a, b));
```

It is also possible to use a reduce, but the syntax is less clear in my opinion.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const b = [1, 4];
const combineAlternatingArrays = (a, b) => {
  const [shorter, larger] = [a, b].sort((a, b) => a.length -b.length);

  return shorter.reduce(
    (combined, next, i, shorter) => {
      return (i === (shorter.length -1)) ? [...combined, larger[i], next, ...larger.slice(shorter.length)] : [...combined, larger[i], next];
    },
    []
  );
}
console.log(combineAlternatingArrays(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) this can be implemented generically for any amount of arrays of any lengths. The key is going through all arrays regardless of length in order and then adding each of the values they have into a single merged array.

By using the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) of arrays we can uniformly proceed through the items in each array.

When producing some sequence of alternating values of other sequences, that is frequently called an [interleave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleave_sequence). Sometimes also called a [Faro shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faro_shuffle) - it's more widely known with playing cards - a perfect Faro shuffle combines two piles of cards in such a way that cards from each pile alternate. However, this is an example of an interleave sequence and mathematicians also use the term to describe the process of interleaving.

```js
//go through all arrays and produce their values
function* parallelWalkAllArrays(...arrays) {
  //get iterator for each array
  const iterators = arrays.map(arr => arr[Symbol.iterator]());
  
  let values;
  
  //loop until complete
  while (true) {
    values = iterators
      .map(it => it.next())      //advance iterators
      .filter(({done}) => !done) //keep anything that is not finished
      .map(({value}) => value);  //get the values
      
    //quit if all are exhausted
    if (values.length === 0)
      return;
     
    //yield a tuple of all values
    yield values;
  }
}

function interleaveMergeArrays(...arrays) {
  //start a generator function
  const sequence = parallelWalkAllArrays(...arrays);
  
  let merged = [];
  //flatten each result into a single array
  for (const result of sequence) {
    merged.push(...result)
  }
  
  return merged;
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

console.log(
  interleaveMergeArrays(array1, array2)
);

const shortArray = ["apple", "banana"];

console.log(
  interleaveMergeArrays(array1, shortArray)
);
console.log(
  interleaveMergeArrays(shortArray, array2)
);
console.log(
  interleaveMergeArrays(array1, shortArray, array2)
);
```

Alternatively, you can take a very similar approach but directly produce a flat sequence from the generator. That way you can consume it immediately.

```js
//go through all arrays and produce their values
function* walkAllArrays(...arrays) {
  //get iterator for each array
  const iterators = arrays.map(arr => arr[Symbol.iterator]());

  let values;

  //loop until complete
  while (true) {
    values = iterators
      .map(it => it.next())      //advance iterators
      .filter(({done}) => !done) //keep anything that is not finished
      .map(({value}) => value);  //get the values

    //quit if all are exhausted
    if (values.length === 0)
      return;

    //yield each value
    for (const value of values) 
      yield value;
  }
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

console.log(Array.from(
  walkAllArrays(array1, array2)
));

const shortArray = ["apple", "banana"];

console.log(Array.from(
  walkAllArrays(array1, shortArray)
));
console.log(Array.from(
  walkAllArrays(shortArray, array2)
));
console.log(Array.from(
  walkAllArrays(array1, shortArray, array2)
));
```

I personally find the latter approach less flexible, as it only solves this problem. Doing a parallel sequential walk through all arrays can be re-used for other things such as zipping arrays, so having a helper function consume the output of that seems like it can leave more options open. On the other hand having a single function makes it a bit more straightforward to see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use **[nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)** for such a scenario:

```js
var mergeAlternately = (a, b) => {
  const maxLength = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
  let result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    result.push( (a[i] ?? '') , (b[i] ?? ''));
  } 
  // Remove empty array values
  return result.filter(item => item);
};

let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = [1, 2];

console.log(mergeAlternately(array1, array2))
```

Answer (score 0):

More modern, efficient and shorter way:

```js
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
const arr2 = [1, 2]

const res = (arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2) // you can replace it with just arr1, if you know its always longer
            .flatMap((e, idx) => arr2[idx] ? [e, arr2[idx]] : [e])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

using an iterator:

```
function *gen(arr1, arr2){
    for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++) {
        if (arr1[i]) yield arr1[i];
        if (arr2[i]) yield arr2[i];
    }
}
const x = gen(['a','b','c','d'], [1,2]);
const result = [...x];
```

gives

```
Array(6) [ "a", 1, "b", 2, "c", "d" ]
```