# How can I make an array of objects follow a "striped" pattern based on a key value?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects that represent some funding data. Each object has a key name "type" that is either c or e. I need to return a table that makes sure the order of the rows follows this pattern: c row => e row => c row => e row... etc.

The data comes back by an ID in desc order and they can be deleted so if there is an original dataset

```
[{type: 'c', id: 1}, {type: 'e', id: 2}, {type: 'c', id: 3}, {type: 'e', id: 4}]
```

and we remove the first `{type: 'e', id: 2}` I want the table to display

```
[{type: 'c', id: 1}, {type: 'e', id: 4}, {type: 'c', id: 3}]
```

**NOT**

```
[{type: 'c', id: 1}, {type: 'c', id: 3}, {type: 'e', id: 4}]
```

Is there a way to utilize javascript's sort() here or do I need to write a custom sort function and if so, what would that look like?

Comment: That's not something you can easily sort for, as there is no good comparison that defines your pattern. It depends on absolute positioning.

Comment: your question is not clear: what is the relationship between `{type: 'e', id: 2}` and `{type: '3', id: 4}`.

Comment: what is the meaning of `type: '3'` ? Why are you not answering my previous question when you had coming back ?

Comment: @MisterJojo It was a type. Fixed now.

Comment: the first element `e` should be changed just because the second element `e` has an `id` with a higher value, and unchanged if that value is lower? the final array must only contain 3 elements (c, e, c) even if the starting array contains 5 elements (c, e, c, e, c) or more. the first 2 (c) can never be changed? even if the following (c) have higher id's? Where is the logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use sort in any way here.

The easiest solution, I think, to make sure it follows your pattern would be to split your array in 2 smaller arrays, one with all `type: 'c'` and another with all `type: 'e'`, then re-merging them together every time you make a change to it.

Something like :

```js
let originalArray = [{type: 'c', id: 1}, {type: 'e', id: 2}, {type: 'c', id: 3}, {type: 'e', id: 4}];
originalArray.splice(2, 1)
let arrayOfTypeE = originalArray.filter(item => item.type === 'e');
let arrayOfTypeC = originalArray.filter(item => item.type === 'c');
let finalArray = [];
for (i = 0; i< arrayOfTypeE.length + arrayOfTypeC.length; i++){
    if(i %2 === 0){
        finalArray[i] = arrayOfTypeE[Math.floor(i / 2)];
    } else {
        finalArray[i] = arrayOfTypeC[Math.floor(i / 2)];
    }
}

finalArray.forEach((e,i)=>console.log(i, '=>' ,JSON.stringify(e)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

But you need to be sure there won't be an array that's 2 elements shorter than the other, otherwise it become impossible to maintain your pattern. And the whole splitting/re-merging could be made into a function

Comment: where is passed the `{type: '3', id: 4}`   original element ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I assumed it was a typo, as '3' and 'e' are very close to each other, and the second and third lines of code in the original question have an object with an id: 4 and a type: 'e'

Comment: @JulienRipet removing the splice and adding conditions to make sure `cop[Math.floor(i/2)]` and `eop[Math.floor(1/2)]` are not undefined seems to give me the result I want. If you edit your answer to reflect those changes I can accept it

Comment: Related: [Merge two arrays with alternating Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47061160) and [Merge Two Arrays so that the Values Alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13253856)

Comment: this answer produce an `[ e , c , e ]` not an  `[ c, e, c ]` as expected by the PO...