# Merging two Array one after another Javascript [equal length]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to merge two array into one,one after another is there any better way?

for example ,

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr2 = [a,b,c,d,e];

const resultIWant = [1,a,2,b,3,c,4,d,5,e]
```

Comment: zipper arrays, asked plenty of times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two arrays with alternating values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061160/merge-two-arrays-with-alternating-values)

Answer (score 3):

Short and clear if both arrays are same length:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
const arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

const res = arr1.flatMap((e, idx) => [e, arr2[idx]])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easily using the `reduce` method. Here is my example below, I iterate through `arr1` using `reduce()` and as I push the current value (`c`) to the accumulator (`a`), I also push the value from `arr2` of the same index.

In my code below, this looks like `a.push(c, arr2[i])` but you could also achieve this using `a.push(arr1[i], arr2[i])`, using `arr1[i]` instead of `c` if you want to keep both push values looking consistent.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

const result = arr1.reduce((a,c,i) => (a.push(c, arr2[i]), a), []);
console.log(result);
```